# Can someone illustrate with example, how and where "pd.groupby()" could be used?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am little stumbled upon the utility of `pd.groupby()` of pandas module.

For example, this is a code snippet I have found.

```
studios=movies.groupby("Studios")

Studios["Gross"].count().head()
```

Can someone explain how and where we apply `pd.groupby()`?

Comment: Have you checked the doc of `pd.groupby()`? Can you find it?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, actually I forgot to check the documentation. Definitely, I will visit this section and find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs) is very well written, **use it!**.

From the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) page, here is how to find the average max speed per Animal:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

#    Animal  Max Speed
# 0  Falcon      380.0
# 1  Falcon      370.0
# 2  Parrot       24.0
# 3  Parrot       26.0

df.groupby(['Animal']).mean()
#         Max Speed
# Animal
# Falcon      375.0
# Parrot       25.0
```

Many more wonderful example there. **Go read it!**